# How to draw a graphic using axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How to draw this graph in LaTeX?
[image: Series of parabola]

Here is an orientation code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, grid=major, xmin=-7,
xmax=7, ymin=-30, ymax=30, height=60mm, width=70mm]
\plot[blueline, line width=1pt] plot[domain=-4:4, samples=100]
expression{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, may I suggest making a more descriptive title? For example "How to plot multiple quadratics with different styles with pgfplots?" or something along those lines. (Assuming that is the actual question you wanted answered.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually a bit surprised that `\plot` works, the documented syntax for `pgfplots` is `\addplot`, or in plain Tikz, `\draw plot`.

That said, you strictly speaking have pretty much all you need already, you could just add more plots, with different expressions. To make a line red and dashed, add `red, dashed` to the options of the `\addplot`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-7, xmax=7,
  ymin=-30, ymax=30,
  height=60mm, width=70mm,
  domain=-7:7, samples=20
  ]

\addplot[blue, line width=1pt] {x^2};
\addplot[red, dashed, line width=1pt] {-0.5*x^2};
% and so on, add more \addplots
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here I changed from `\plot [...] plot [...]` to `\addplot[...]`, since that is the "proper" syntax for `pgfplots`. You didn't show the definition of the `blueline` style, so I just replaced that with `blue`.

For convenience I also moved the `domain` and `samples` setting to the `axis` options, that way they apply to all the plots.

It is possible to automate this a bit though, using `\foreach`

```
\foreach \a in {-2.1,-1.5,...,2.1}
   \addplot[red, dashed, line width=0.3pt]  {\a*x^2};
```

Note that looping inside an `axis` environment doesn't always work, though it does in this case. Chapter 8 in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) talks about this, though it might be a bit technical.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  grid=major,
  xmin=-7, xmax=7,
  ymin=-30, ymax=30,
  height=60mm, width=70mm,
  domain=-7:7, samples=50
  ]

  \foreach \a in {-2.1,-1.5,...,2.1}
     \addplot[red, dashed, line width=0.3pt]  {\a*x^2};

   \foreach \a in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}
        \addplot[blue, line width=0.3pt]  {\a*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I partially succeeded ... but where is the problem ... because most of the lines are not drawn to the end of the graph

Comment: @Amela The `domain` setting perhaps. You had it set to `-4:4`, so the graphs are drawn for x-values from -4 to 4. One thing I forgot to mention was that I changed that setting to `domain=-7:7`, corresponding to the x-limits you had set for the axis.

Comment: Yes, that was a problem. Thanks soo much :)

Comment: @Amela `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` is using `\foreach`, do you need anything else? If using foreach in the normal way doesn't work, have a look at the example in the pgfplots manual.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, grid=major, xmin=-7, xmax=7,xtick={-6,-4,...,6}, ymin=-30, ymax=30, domain=-7:7, samples=20, y=\a*x^2]
\addplot[redline, dashed, linewidth=0.3pt] \foreach \a in {-2.1,-1.5,...,2.1};
\addplot[blueline2, smooth] \foreach \a in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}        heelp

Comment: @Amela The `y` option when added to the `axis` options is *not* meant to provide a general function used for y-coordinates. It is  a scaling option, setting the length if the unit vector in the y-direction. Further, `redline` is not a default style, so unless you've defined that elsewhere, that will cause an error. And `linewidth` should be `line width` (with a space). You need the whole `\addplot` inside the loop, i.e. `\foreach \a in {-2.1,-1.5,...,2.1}     \addplot[red, dashed, line width=0.3pt]  {\a*x^2};`

Comment: I am very grateful to you :)